# Why does using dynamic variable names in IDE error out, but codesandbox works fine?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Was testing some code in codesandbox, copied the exact code snippet down into VSCode and it threw an error when trying to start with nodemon.

Code snippet:

```
test.js:96
      hostFile.[itemGroup].add(item.name)
               ^
sourceData.forEach(item => {
  item.itemGroups.forEach(itemGroup => {
    if(Object.keys(hostFile).find(el => el === itemGroup)){
      hostFile.[itemGroup].add(item.name)
    } else {
      hostFile.[itemGroup] = new Set()
      hostFile.[itemGroup].add(item.name)
    }
  })
})
```

Error from nodemon:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: No, it should be `hostFile[itemGroup]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use both `[]` and `.` notations. If your property is dynamic, then use `[]`, if not, then you can use `.`.

```js
sourceData.forEach(item => {
  item.itemGroups.forEach(itemGroup => {
    if(Object.keys(hostFile).find(el => el === itemGroup)){
      hostFile[itemGroup].add(item.name)
    } else {
      hostFile[itemGroup] = new Set()
      hostFile[itemGroup].add(item.name)
    }
  })
})
```

#### More explanation on differences:

If you have variable `itemGroup` that contains ex. value `"test"`, then this `hostFile[itemGroup]` will call property `test` of `hostFile`. Whereas `hostFile.itemGroup` will call property `itemGroup` of `hostFile`.